# Auto-connect VPN in Kali Linux?

Tags: kali-linux, networkmanager, vpn, autostart, boot-process

I currently have a working VPN on my Kali Linux box however I feel uncomfortable with the fact that sometimes I forget to manually connect it in the network manager.

After digging around everywhere in the `gnome-control-center network` I can't seem to find anyway to initiate the VPN connection automatically.

Is there something I am missing or perhaps an alternative for a network manager GUI? If not, how could I add the terminal commands to execute during the boot process?

Answer (score 4):

Does your system have a `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections` directory populated with connection profiles?

I've a `kali-rolling` build which is very much like setting up as described in an Ubuntu related [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1144855/172838) I posted about configuring such things for a particular interface. The TLDR version is as follows...

#### `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/WiFI_AP`

```
[connection]
id=WiFI_AP
uuid=aaaa-0000-aaaa-0000
type=wifi
autoconnect=true
autoconnect-priority=9000
permissions=
secondaries=deadbeef-d3ad-b33f-dead-be33e3f;
autoconnect-slaves=1
vpn.timeout=120
# ... more connection config blocks...
```

#### `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/VPN_Client`

```
[connection]
id=VPN_Client
uuid=deadbeef-d3ad-b33f-dead-be33e3f
type=vpn
permissions=
secondaries=
# ... more connection config blocks...
```

> Note if you're *roaming about* then ya may instead want just the following...

#### `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/VPN_Client`

```
[connection]
id=VPN_Client
uuid=deadbeef-d3ad-b33f-dead-be33e3f
type=vpn
permissions=
secondaries=
autoconnect=true
autoconnect-priority=8999
# ... more connection config blocks...
```

> ... but for me that caused things to *barf* so use at your own risk.

The `secondaries=deadbeef-d3ad-b33f-dead-be33e3f;` line within `WiFI_AP` is a space  separated list of *`uuid`s* of *`slave`* connections that should also be *hooked* the `WiFi_AP` network, in this case the `uuid` from the `VPN_Client` config; side note, these *`list`s* (from what I've gathered) must end with a semicolon **`;`**

The `autoconnect-slaves=1` line within `WiFI_AP` is what *enables* this fancy *hooking* of one network with another. And the `vpn.timeout=120` line may need a longer wait time if you've got VPN certs within an encrypted home directory.

Related manuals maybe found via `man NetworkManager`, `man NetworkManager.conf`, and `man nm-settings`.

Personally I found rebooting to be *safer* than things like *`systemctl reload NetworkManager`* when testing various combos of connection profile modifications.